# Some question on ideal and quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $S,T$ be subrings with unity of a big commutative ring with unity $R$.

Let $I,J$ be ideals of $S$ and $T$ respectively.

Then I am wodering whether quotient ring $IT/I \cap J$ can be embedded into $T/J$.

Does this hold?

Any comments will be appreciated!

Comment: @user26875, Oh, sorry! I corrected my question.

Comment: If one considers the natural map(s) $IT\hookrightarrow T\to T/J$, then its kernel is $IT\cap J$ which I do not think is the same with $I\cap J$ if $I$ is an ideal of an arbitrary subring $S$. However, we can have a non-natural embedding (which I also doubt).